Error message after update last week: "tbl_count_missing_cells:n #1->\tag_if_active:T {\int_compare:nNnT \g__tbl_c..."
Since a few days I get the following message when compiling my documents, in which I load the package “eqexam”:
“tbl_count_missing_cells:n #1->\tag_if_active:T {\int_compare:nNnT \g__tbl_c...”
Perhaps someone knows where this message comes from, because no changes were made in the “eqexam” package during this time.
I found the command “tbl_count_missing_cells:n” in the package “tabulary” by David Carlisle, which has been changed recently.
I would be very happy to receive information on how to solve this problem. Many thanks in advance.
I compile with LaTeX.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eqexam}
\begin{document}
\[  3x+2 = x^2-1 \] 
\end{document}


a new tabulary version has already been uploaded to ctan but didn't make its way into texlive 2024 yet.

@UlrikeFischer thank you very much for this information.

but I don't have the eqexam package so I can't test that the new version will resolve your problem.

@UlrikeFischer thanks, so I will test the new version. Comment on eqexam: it's part of tlcontrib and loadable with TeXLiveManager.

hm, no I checked and your example doesn't load tabulary at all. The error is from something else. I will take a look,

This is great @UlrikeFischer

the package does typesetting in the preamble (it measures a box) which it shouldn't do and which now fails as a command is not defined yet. Add \usepackage{tagpdf-base} before the package, that will work around the problem.

Loading the package fixed the error message for me. Thank you, @UlrikeFischer
